# Как отобразить MessageBox unity3d

Tags: android, c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Как показать окно, аналог MessageBox из Windows Forms, только на андроид?

Что-то вроде такого окна, только указывать свой текст:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если именно с нативной темой, то проще плагин написать нативный.

Comment: То-есть встроенных функций нет?
А может посоветуете, как лучше давать понять, что что-то не сделано? Панель отображать с текстом?

Comment: Делать всё также как и остальные GUI элементы. В игре некрасиво смотрится, когда используются и свои контроллы, и нативные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже написали в комментарии, легче всего сделать нативный плагин для показа стандартного окна. Можете посмотреть туториалы, например [этот](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-native-popup-using-unity). Либо воспользоваться уже готовым [решением](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/mobile-native-popups-18479).